# joining 2 subquerys

Tags: sql, oracle

```
select count(cou_code) as Changes
from sdrp15_cosd    
where sd_code in
(select sd_code from sdrp15_submission_log
where QA_date is  null)
```

It gives me the result

Changes | 629

```
select count(cou_code) as Complete
from sdrp15_cosd    
where sd_code in
(select sd_code from sdrp15_submission_log
where QA_date is not null)
```

It gives me result

Completed | 210

I want to have 2 columns one named changes and one named complete with the two of those queries(above) combined into one query

Comment: MySQL and Oracle are two different products, with slightly different versions of SQL. Which one are you using?

Comment: Can you add some sample data (for all tables involved), and the expected result.

Comment: @jarlh I believe I am using oracle sql

Comment: @jarlh The tables contain 10000 rows so itd be really difficult to type all that here, but for the first query I have 1 row selected and the total count is 629 and the 2nd query is the same but the total count is 210

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do two conditional count (with `CASE`), one for the `is null`'s and one for the `is not null`'s.

```
select count(case when sd_code in (select sd_code from sdrp15_submission_log
                                   where QA_date is null) then 1 end) as Changes,
       count(case when sd_code in (select sd_code from sdrp15_submission_log
                                   where QA_date is not null) then 1 end) as Complete
from sdrp15_cosd
```

Comment: Thanks, But now How do I combine your query(above) and this one:


select a.phase,a.st_code||' - '||b.state_name,
case when a.submission_received_dt is not null then 'Y' else 'N' end as Changes 
from pcspro.sdrp15_return a,
pcspro.sdrp15_states_ready b 
where a.phase = b.phase and a.st_code = b.state;

Answer (score 0):

Try UNION

```
select count(cou_code) as Changes from sdrp15_cosd where sd_code in
(select sd_code from sdrp15_submission_log where QA_date is  null) 
UNION
select count(cou_code) as Complete from sdrp15_cosd where sd_code in
(select sd_code from sdrp15_submission_log where QA_date is not null)
```

Comment: Suggested improvements: Do UNION ALL. Also select 'Complete' in firts part, and 'Changes' in second.